# How do you convert Milliseconds into a Javascript UTC date?

Tags: javascript, azure-table-storage

Given I have the number `1446309338000`, how do I create a JavaScript UTC date?

`new Date(1446309338000)` will equal a CST time (central standard) or local time.
`new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, second))` haven't got this info yet.

Does JavaScript change the time if I do this?

```
new Date(1446309338000).ISOString();
```

Is it creating a new CST date and then converting it to UTC?  I really just need the string.  I am taking it from a database (RowKey from a Azure Table storage database).

Comment: The date object is already in UTC. Are you trying to get the month, day, hour, minute, etc. as UTC?

Comment: For reference, have a look at the methods that Date offers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: `new Date(1446309338000)` is what you want, you just need to access the UTC methods instead of the local time methods. In the _Console_ it shows up in local time because `d.toString()` produces the local time as a string

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have the milliseconds that's already the UTC date. Which basically means the universal time. Now based on those millis you can convert the Date object into a String of your like:

```
new Date(1446309338000).toUTCString() // timezone free universal format
> "Sat, 31 Oct 2015 16:35:38 GMT"
new Date(1446309338000).toString() // browser local timezon string
> "Sat Oct 31 2015 09:35:38 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
new Date(1446309338000).toISOString() // ISO format of the UTC time
> "2015-10-31T16:35:38.000Z"
```

Now, if for some reason (I can't see a valid reason, but just for the heck of it) you're looking for having a different amount of milliseconds that represent a different date but that would print the same in the local browser timezone, you can do this calculation:

```
new Date(1446309338000 - new Date(1446309338000).getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000))
```

Now toString from original Date and toUTCString of this new Date would read the same up to the Timezone information, because of course they're not the same date!

```
new Date(1446309338000).toString()
> "Sat Oct 31 2015 09:35:38 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
new Date(1446309338000 - new Date(1446309338000).getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000).toUTCString()
> "Sat, 31 Oct 2015 09:35:38 GMT"
```

Comment: So then what does this do:  new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, second))?  How would this (UTC) differ from the other constructors?

Comment: @markthegrea `new Date(millis)` is in UTC, because it is the number of milliseconds after 1970-01-01 midnight UTC. Whereas `new Date(y, m, d, h, m, s)` interprets the date-time combo as local time. So `Date.UTC(y, m, d, h, m, s)` interprets the date-time combo as UTC and returns the millis since year 1970.

Answer (score 7):

It's actually as simple as homemade biscuits, If you have your date, say:

```
var date_in_milliseconds = 1504640419000;
```

You can then initialize a new date like this:

```
var human_readable_date = new Date(0); //Date(0) creates a date at the Epoch, so Wed Dec 31 1969
```

now, just add the milliseconds to the Epoch, and this will give us the desired date:

```
human_readable_date.setUTCMilliseconds(date_in_milliseconds);
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, if the date string is what you require, hope this helps:

```
new Date(1446309338000).toLocaleString('en-US', {timeZone: 'UTC'})
```

As far as `toISOString()` is concerned, it returns string representation using ISO-8601 standard (the format is: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ). 

`toLocaleString()` is human readable format with same result.