# Angular Epoch date from custom String

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a custom UTC date in following format.

```
YYYYMMDDHHmmss
```

I want to convert it to epoch and show result, My code is as follows.

```
   const epochNow = new Date(
      +moment("20210316200005", 'YYYYMMDDHHmmss')
    ).getTime();
    console.log('epoch ', epochNow, ' ', currMoment);
```

it shows output as 16159**05005000**  which is not correct. since it add my local timezone.
Date is already in UTC string. correct output should be 16159**24805000**

How to change the code to show correct epoch?

Comment: This should answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33507289/how-do-you-convert-milliseconds-into-a-javascript-utc-date

Comment: Thanks Wahab Memon